# Cucumber::ArityMismatchError

Tags: regex, cucumber, watir

I have these `.feature` statements:

```
I am logged in as an "Teacher".
I am logged in as an "Professor".
I am logged in as an "Student".
I am logged in as a "NoRole"
```

for which I wrote a regex

`I (\w{2})?\s?(log|login|logged)\s?(\w{2}) as (an|a) "(Teacher|Professor|Student|NoRole)"\.?`

I had put them in quotes so that I can run a case block on them like this:

```
case role_type
     when 'Student'
       on(LoginPage).login_with(FigNewton.Studnet_email,'password')
and so on ... for other roles
```

Now when I run this regex in step definitions with `Given`

```
Given(/^I (\w{2})?\s?(log|login|logged)\s?(\w{2}) as (an|a) "(Teacher|Professor|Student|NoRole)"\.?$/) do |user_role|
  # code
end
```

it gives this error:

`Cucumber::ArityMismatchError: Your block takes 1 argument, but the Regexp matched 5 arguments`

Query: As far as I know, arguments are those in between quotes like "Professor" so which five arguments it is talking about.

On this [Cucumber::ArityMismatchError error after Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450137/cucumberaritymismatcherror-error-after-transform) I found that there shouldn't be any block, but my `regex` wont work if there are no blocks, 
So how to separated role type from `regex arguments(blocks)`

Comment: The problem here is the same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450137/cucumberaritymismatcherror-error-after-transform). The arguments are the capture groups returned by the Regexp. The capture groups are seen by the brackets not the quotations - ie the arguements/groups are `(\w{2})`, `(log|login|logged)`, `(\w{2})`, `(an|a)`, and `(Teacher|Professor|Student|NoRole)`. The same approach as the answer in the other question is required - ie do not capture or make non-capturing groups.

Comment: @JustinKo thats why I posted the question, **my regex wont work if there are no blocks, So how to separated role type from regex arguments(blocks)??**

Comment: Are you saying that you do not want to do `Given(/^I (?:\w{2})?\s?(?:log|login|logged)\s?(?:\w{2}) as (?:an|a) "(Teacher|Professor|Student|NoRole|Owner)"\.?$/)`

Comment: I want all my `.feature` sentences should work in one `regex`, which also give separate string `role type` in quotes. So that I can run `case:` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, the step definition is expecting one argument - `user_role`. However, you are capturing 5 groups, which means you are passing 5 arguments:

- (\w{2})
- (log|login|logged)
- (\w{2})
- (an|a)
- (Teacher|Professor|Student|NoRole)

Given that you only want the last group, `(Teacher|Professor|Student|NoRole)`, the other 4 groups should be marked as non-capturing groups. This is done by adding a `?:` after the opening parenthesis:

```
Given(/^I (?:\w{2})?\s?(?:log|login|logged)\s?(?:\w{2}) as (?:an|a) "(Teacher|Professor|Student|NoRole|Owner)"\.?$/)
```

Note that the "Owner" role was missing from the user_role group (and is added above). This step will match all 5 of the expected steps.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly off topic from the question, but don't write step definitions like this, its far to painful. One of the biggest mistakes cucumber users make, is trying to make step definitions DRY. It doesn't matter how many step definitions you have. The important thing is that the contents of the step definitions are DRY. You can do this by making them calls to helper methods.

In your case I would just implement

```
Given "I am logged in as a teacher" do
  login_as :teacher
end

and then implement

module LoginStepHelper
  def login_as(user_type)
    ...
  end
end
World LoginStepHelper
```

It doesn't matter if you have twenty different step definitions that call this method, because you only have one implementation, so if you change how you login you only have to change one thing. In addition your step defs are so simple you'll never waste time debugging why a particular statement doesn't match.

Now I'm quite happy to have

```
Given "I am logged in as a teacher" do
  login_as :teacher
end

Given "I log in as a teacher" do
  login_as :teacher
end

Given "I am logged in as a artist" do
  login_as :artist
end

...
```

Yes it may be a little tedious, but each one is clear and simple, and creating new ones to meet new language uses is trivial e.g.

```
Given "I am signed in as a artist" do
  login_as :artist
end
```

Compare that to the dangers of modifying your hugely complex regex.